# How to get sum of all the keys in python list of tuples?

Tags: python

I am very new to python and I was wondering how to get the following dictionary from the list of tuples?

## Question

```py
x = [('A',1),('B',2),('C',3),('A',10),('B',10)]
required_dict = {'A': 11,'B': 12, 'C': 3}
```

Comment: What happened when you tried to write code to solve the problem? How would you solve the problem with pencil and paper? Can you write out steps that make sense?

Comment: @Liam, yes i can make two list for keys and values and do for loop, but i was trying to learn more advanced approaches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest way IMO is using `defaultdict` and a single `for` loop:

```
from collections import defaultdict

required_dict = defaultdict(int)
for k, v in x:
    required_dict[k] += v
```

You could also do this in a single line with a nested comprehension, but this is less efficient because it involves iterating over `x` repeatedly instead of doing it in a single pass:

```
required_dict = {k: sum(v for k1, v in x if k1 == k) for k, v in x}
```

Another comprehension-based solution that doesn't involve redundant iteration would be to use `groupby` in order to iterate only within each group of identical keys:

```
from itertools import groupby

required_dict = {
    k: sum(v for _, v in g) 
    for k, g in groupby(sorted(x), key=lambda t: t[0])
}
```

These three approaches are respectively:

- O(n) (single iteration)
- O(n^2) (re-iteration for each element)
- O(nlogn) (a full sort followed by a single iteration)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your promt answer,  but I was learning using for loop or using dictionary comprehension if its that possible.

Comment: My first solution uses a for loop, my second uses a comprehension.  Are you saying you need a solution that *doesn't* use either of those things?

Comment: I think `collections.Counter` might be preferable over `defaultdict(int)`.